# 500 - Internal server error PHP - IIS 7.0

Tags: php, iis-7, plesk

In a PHP page i have a form like

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

but whenever i submit the form it gives me error message like

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

My site is on running on following configuration

Server:- `Microsoft-IIS/7.0`

PHP version:- `PHP5.3.0`

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: When you look at the source code of your HTML form, do you see the right url in the action attribute? - `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` may contain more than you wanted, try using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead, if you have some garbage in action

Comment: what php handler do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 500 is an internal server error**
so there is a server side issue

you can review the iss / php logs for more details about it

Comment: If you are not familiar with IIS, please contact the vendor for documentation and training. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661688/iis-php-doesnt-log-errors-to-log-file   plz +1 my answer if u like it